# Can't build React Native 0.59.8 android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, androidx, react-native-community-netinfo

I migrated to the newer React Native and updated some libraries to the latest version. A piece of my `project.json`:

```
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.1",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^3.1.1",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "^0.59.8"
```

I'm getting this issue here:

> D:\myapp\node_modules@react-native-community\netinfo\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\netinfo\ConnectivityReceiver.java:12:
>   error: package android.support.v4.net does not exist import
>   android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat;
>                                ^ D:\myapp\node_modules@react-native-community\netinfo\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\netinfo\ConnectivityReceiver.java:154:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                       ConnectivityManagerCompat.isActiveNetworkMetered(getConnectivityManager());
>                       ^   symbol:   variable ConnectivityManagerCompat   location: class ConnectivityReceiver 2 errors

**gradle.properties**

```
android.enableJetifier = true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

**root gradle**

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion="28.0.0"
}
```

**gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to switch off gradle AndroidX and jettifier because some libraries are still dependent on old support libraries and have deprecated dependencies that can't be migrated to AndroidX easily.

Comment: Check how to fix AndroidX breaking changes https://twitter.com/jdnichollsc/status/1162451046544879616

Answer (score 0):

that because your sdk have problem when update to platform 28

open android studio

open sdk manager

check to "show package detail"

under package platform 28, tick to "source for android" or something like that i dont remember, but it is source for package 28. Click ok to download it

rebuild to check

hope this help